# Funcion convertir de año a siglo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Esta consulta sql es para convertir de un anno a el siglo de este... lo que pasa es que **para los casos que son años multiplos de 100 no me funciona** dado que Ej:1900 pertenece al ultimo año del siglo 19, al igual que 2000 al siglo 20, etc... y mi problema es que no se como poner las condiciones if en sql para el caso que el modulo de `yr/100=0` hacer algo, o sino mantener mi `yr/100+1`...

`select (yr/100+1) as century from years`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta imagen es de mi query para los años 1705, 1923, 1600, 2000, 444 y 88 respectivamente...

Estoy utilizando `PostgreSQL 9.6` la tabla es years y la columna yr

Comment: Creo que deberías hacerlo así: `select (yr-1/100)+1 as century from years`.

Comment: gracias the @the-breaker me funciona bien pensaba q de esta forma tendria un anno dentro del siglo para el que no me funcionaria pero no es asi...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa directamente [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html) indicando como parámetro `century`:

```
SELECT date_part('century',TIMESTAMP '1900-01-01');

| date_part |
|-----------|
|        19 |

SELECT date_part('century',TIMESTAMP '1901-01-01');

| date_part |
|-----------|
|        20 |
```

En caso que solo tengas un año como dato, podrías hacer:

```
select (yr + 99) / 100
```

Comment: Gracias! Patricio muy util los dos casos saludos